# Manage Content Types in Site Pages library

Tags: library, content-type

Is it possible to manage content types for the Site Pages library in the browser? If this is not possible, what's the rationale that this can be done in nearly every library and list, but not Site Pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The OnLoad event of the Advanced Settings page hides the Content Types section with the following code:

```
this.ContentTypeSection.Visible = this.List.AllowContentTypes 
    && this.List.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.UserInformation 
    && this.List.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.WebPageLibrary;
```

I do not know the reason why it is protected, but it is definitely explicitly singled out along with the User Information list. That said, you might be able to set [ContentTypesEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypesenabled.aspx) using code. But you will likely be in unsupported territory if you do so. If possible, you may want to consider using Publishing Pages, as those support multiple content types.

Answer (score 1):

I think they want you to use the Enteprise Wiki functionality if you want Content Types and Wiki pages. The Enterprise Wiki functionality uses the Publishing Pages library (unlike ordinary Wiki pages that use the Site Pages library) and the Pages library has Content Type management enabled for the whole Page Layout Publishing architecture to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but I have found that if you open the Site Pages library in SharePoint Designer, you can enable management of content types from there.

Comment: The downside to answering old questions here, is that the question was likely specific to whatever version of SharePoint the OP was using at the time.  Newer versions (not sure where the cutoff was) actually Do allow content type management in SitePages directly in the browser. Unfortunately, the OP didn't tag this with which version they were using, but since it was posted in 2011, it couldn't possibly be any version newer than SharePoint 2010 -- did you validate that your answer works in older versions?